# Reformat vector

Tags: r, vector

here is my dataframe

```
df <- read.table(text="
 unit 
 (15,30]
 (60,75]
 (75,90]
 (45,60]
",header=TRUE)
```

I'd like to reformat this as 15 - 30 AND be able to sort this data by value, in other words, I'd like to be able to use min() command. Which should return 15 - 30, or max() that will return 75 - 90.

Comment: That is not a good data format design, You should look at splitting them in columns

Answer (score 0):

Even though the format is bad and the correct way is to correct the format from the source, a workaround can be a simple regex that extracts the first value and converts to numeric. i.e.

```
df$v1 <- as.numeric(gsub('^\\((\\d+),\\d+]$', '\\1', df$unit))
#[1] 15 60 75 45

df[which.min(df$v1),]
#     unit v1
#1 (15,30] 15
df[which.max(df$v1),]
#     unit v1
#3 (75,90] 75
```